# How to add a wordpress setup within another wordpress setup?

Tags: wordpress

I've a wordpress website running on "example/"
I want to run another wordpress installation within that as "example/example2/"
Currently, after creating a folder named "example2", the home page loads fine but the links show up as 404. for example: "example/example2/category/category1" redirects to the parent setup's wordpress 404 page(which makes sense from the POV of the parent setup). How can I make the 2 setups exclusive, I cannot delete the existing root setup, I only have control on the child setup. Also, since I'm running on a network server I don't have any cpanel creds to create a subdomain under the existing setup.

Comment: What plugins do you have installed? I had Better WP Security plugin installed and it gave me this issue, so I deactivated it and the second wordpress folder worked. So maybe check if it's a plugin conflict...

Comment: Can you please tell us how you are trying to install. FTP ? or using cpanel? If its on shared hosting better to upload wordpress into subfolder example1/example2 and follow instructions of Leo. If you are using vps or cloud better to use a panel like runcloud instead of going through all these hassles. If you can let us know whr you are doing it it would be easier for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

> after creating a folder named "example2", the home page loads fine but the links show up as 404

It's because you have created just a directory and it doesn't have any files like index.php inside (default pages). So the 404 error page is redirecting you.

All you have to do is install WordPress inside the subfolder, say `example2`:

```
cd /home/account_name/public_html
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.zip
unzip latest.zip
mv wordpress example2
```

Then create a database, user and allow full access to the user for the database from cPanel > MySQL databases.

Now try to load the link `http://domain.com/example2`. This won't lead you to a 404 error anymore; instead you can complete the WordPress installation.

If you have Softaculous with cPanel, then install WordPress by defining the path as `/example2`. Either way will work for you.

Please let me know if you have any issues!